# Observable template in modern C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I'm trying to create a modern template class for a generic observable:

```
typedef int SUBSCRIPTION_ID;

template<typename EventType, typename Event>
    class Subject2
    {
        typedef struct
        {
            std::function<void(const Event&)> method;
            int id;
        } Callable2;

    public:
        virtual SUBSCRIPTION_ID subscribe(const EventType& event, std::function<void(const Event&)>&& call)
        {
            Callable2 this_call = { call, ++last_id_ };
            observers_[event].push_back(this_call);
            return this_call.id;
        }

        virtual void unsubscribe(const EventType& event, SUBSCRIPTION_ID subscription)
        {
            std::vector<Callable2>& subscribers = observers_[event];
            for (auto& obs = subscribers.begin(); obs != subscribers.end(); ++obs) {
                if ((*obs).id == subscription) {
                    subscribers.erase(obs);
                    return;
                }
            }
            assert(false);
            return;
        }

    protected:
        void fire(const Event& data)
        {
            auto& subscribers = observers_[data.event];
            for (const auto& obs : subscribers) {
                obs.method(data);
            }
        }

    protected:
        std::map<EventType, std::vector<Callable2>> observers_;
        int last_id_ = 0;
    };
```

(obviously `Subject2` and `Callable2` are in fact `Subject` and `Callable`)

A simple example of how I use it is:

```
something->subscribe(MouseEvent::Type::MOVE, [&](const MouseEvent& evt) { 
    do_something_usefull();
});
```

The code runs quite ok, however there are a couple of things that I'm sure they could be improved but am unsure how:

First is the technique I use for unsubscribing, as the code shows I create an ID and store it within the `Callable2` struct that is pushed into the vector. Ideally this could be done without the need for such artifact and extra level of indirection but then, how?

Second, I don't really understand why the `Callable2` structure can't be written as to store a reference rather than a function object, tried unsuccessfully with:

```
    typedef struct
    {
        std::function<void(const Event&)>& method;
        int id;
    } Callable2;
```

Last but not least, another thing I was trying was to simplify the template from

```
template<typename EventType, typename Event>
```

To

```
template<typename Event>
```

but then it won't compile if I try:

```
virtual SUBSCRIPTION_ID subscribe(const Event::Type& event, std::function<void(const Event&)>&& call)
```

as it seems the `Event::Type&` upsets the compiler, which I'm highly suspicious as to not to be valid C++.

Obviously, my `Event` struct has a `Type`:

```
typedef struct
{
    Point at;
    enum class Type
    {
        MOVE,
        LEFT_DOWN,
        LEFT_UP,
        RIGHT_DOWN,
        RIGHT_UP
    } event;
} MouseEvent;
```

Any suggestions? I'm currently using VS 2013.

EDIT1:
Based on Alejandro's feedback, which has good points I reworked it as:

```
namespace observable
{
    template<typename Event>
    class Subject
    {
        using EventType = typename Event::Type;

    public:
        virtual int subscribe(const EventType& event, std::function<void(const Event&)>&& call)
        {
            observers_[event].emplace_back(std::move(call), ++last_id_);
            return last_id_;
        }

        virtual void unsubscribe(const EventType& event, int subscription)
        {
            auto& subscribers = observers_[event];
            auto to_remove = std::remove_if(subscribers.begin(),
                                            subscribers.end(),
                                            [=](const std::pair<std::function<void(const Event&)>, int>& observer) {
                return observer.second == subscription;
            });
            if (to_remove == subscribers.end())
            {
                throw std::exception("Invalid subscription");
            }
            subscribers.erase(to_remove);
        }

    protected:
        void fire(const Event& evt)
        {
            auto& subscribers = observers_[evt.event];
            for (const auto& obs : subscribers) {
                obs.first(evt);
            }
        }

    protected:
        std::unordered_map<EventType, std::vector<std::pair<std::function<void(const Event&)>, int>>> observers_;
        int last_id_ = 0;
    };
}
```

And a simple test that shows / proves it's intended usage:

```
typedef struct
{
    bool is_interesting;
    enum class Type
    {
        MOVE,
        ENTER,
        LEAVE
    } event;
} MyEvent;


class TestObservable : public observable::Subject <MyEvent>
{
public:
    void fire_move() {
        MyEvent evt = { true, MyEvent::Type::MOVE };
        fire(evt);
    }
};

void test_observable()
{
    int observer_1_move_fired = 0;
    int observer_2_move_fired = 0;

    TestObservable test_subject;

    int subscription_1 = test_subject.subscribe(MyEvent::Type::MOVE, [&](const MyEvent& evt) {
        assert(evt.event == MyEvent::Type::MOVE);
        observer_1_move_fired++;
    });

    int subscription_2 = test_subject.subscribe(MyEvent::Type::MOVE, [&](const MyEvent& evt) {
        assert(evt.event == MyEvent::Type::MOVE);
        observer_2_move_fired++;
    });

    test_subject.fire_move();
    assert(observer_1_move_fired == 1);
    assert(observer_2_move_fired == 1);

    //observer 2 should not receive MOVE events anymore...
    test_subject.unsubscribe(MyEvent::Type::MOVE, subscription_2);

    test_subject.fire_move();
    assert(observer_1_move_fired == 2);
    assert(observer_2_move_fired == 1);
}
```

Only consideration is that the event struct must have an enum class Type and be named event, but this can be easily relaxed / refactored if desired, certainly a comment in the template about it would be a sensible thing to do :)

And yes std::exception is a placeholder for a more appropriate one.

Thanks! great tips!

Comment: I'll write up an answer later with more explanation, but some things I noticed that could be improved are:  `typdef struct{...}name;` could be replaced by `struct name{...};`, in your subscribe function you're taking a temporary `std::function` but not further `move`ing it, you could use `emplace_back` directly instead of `push`-ing back a temporary, and perhaps consider the erase-remove in the `unsubscribe` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few things I'd consider changing in your code, especially since you state that you'd like to transition to modern C++.

Using struct variables in C++ doesn't require prefixing them with the `struct` keyword as is needed in C, so your `typedef struct {...} Callable2;`, which I imagine you wrote so that you could get away with `Callable2  foo;` as opposed to `struct Callable2 foo;` could be changed to simply `struct Callable2 {...};` without any change in the usage of that struct.

In your `subscribe` member function, you take as one of your parameters, an rvalue reference to `std::function<void(const Event&)>` - in other words, a temporary. However, you don't subsequently `move` the temporary so as to take advantage of possible optimizations that `move`ing a `std::function` could have as opposed to copying it. You could remedy this by initializing `this_call` with `{std::move(call),++last_id_}`. However, even with this, you'll still end up pushing back a copy of the `Callable2` you just created and effectively nullify the benefit of `move`ing the `std::function`. An alternative approach you could perhaps consider would be:

```
Callable2 this_call = { std::move(call), ++last_id_ };
observers_[event].push_back(std::move(this_call));
return last_id_;
```

Which avoids the copy of the `std::function` into the vector. But this still requires a move of a `Callable2`. Perhaps an even better approach would be:

```
observers_[event].emplace_back(std::move(call),++last_id_);
return last_id_;
```

And the only `move` done is on the `std::function`. This would require you, however,  to add the appropriate constructor within `Callable2`, but it does the least amount of operations regarding copying and moving.

Your `unsubscribe` function could also benefit from the erase-remove idiom, which is by no means "modern" advice but still does the job possibly more efficiently and becomes much more readable and easier to maintain. By looking at `unsubscribe` it appears you want to purge an event with a specific ID and signal some emergency (which you're doing by asserting false) if the event doesn't exist. With the erase-remove idiom, `unsubscribe` would instead look like this:

```
auto& subscribers = observers_[event];
auto to_remove = std::remove_if(subscribers.begin(),subscribers.end(),[sub=subscription](const auto& observer)
                 {
                    return observer.id == sub;
                 });
if(to_remove == subscribers.end())
{
   // consider throwing an exception instead of assert(false)
}
subscribers.erase(to_remove,subscribers.end());
```

This more clearly expresses your intent than manually looping, comparing, etc. You can even opt for `std::find_if` which stops as soon as it finds the first occurrence of a condition you specify, which might be more efficient than `std::remove_if` depending upon the size of your events vector. I also mentioned throwing an exception rather than doing a blatant `assert(false)` for a whole host of reasons. I point you to Jon Kalb's [excellent 3-part talk at CppCon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W7fIy_54y-w) for matters regarding exceptions, exception safe code, and its benefits.

You didn't quite express if your events need to be ordered. In the case that they don't, consider using a `std::unordered_map` to map your `Event`s, which provides a hash-table container as opposed to a balanced binary search tree that `std::map` gives you. This would also require that `EventType` be hashable.

On a minor note, at the beginning of your code, you're typedef-ing a `SUBSCRIPTION_ID` for an int, but there's honestly little need for `typedef`s in modern C++ unless you're working with an older codebase. An alias declaration not only gives you the same semantics and behavior as a `typedef`, but also comes in handy if you ever want to have alias templates, which requires more boilerplate code if it were done with the equivalent `typedef`, not to mention being more readable. Use `using SUBSCRIPTION_ID = int;` to replace your current typedef.

To answer your questions,

- Holding a reference (even if its a const ref) would limit how freely you can use this struct. Namely, it becomes unassignable, thus makes it unusable with `std::remove_if`, among other limitations. The alternative, which is to store a pointer, becomes unsafe as soon as that `std::function` goes out of scope and destructs.
- Since `Event::Type` names a type, you need to prefix it with `typename`. A  solution would be to create an alias declaration `using EventType = typename Event::Type;` within your class. For more info on `typename` see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)